# pm2 script execution path is incorrect, doesn't match the one in ecosystem.config.js

Tags: node.js, deployment, pm2

My ecosystem.config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
apps: [{
    name: 'production',
    script: '/home/username/sites/Website/source/server.js',
    env: { NODE_ENV: 'PRODUCTION' },
    args: '--run-server'
}, {
    name: 'staging',
    script: '/home/username/sites/WebsiteStaging/source/server.js',
    env: { NODE_ENV: 'STAGING' },
    args: '--run-server'
}],
deploy: {
    production: {
        user: 'username',
        host: ['XXX.XXX.XX.XXX'],
        ref: 'origin/production',
        repo: 'git@github.com:ghuser/Website.git',
        path: '/home/username/sites/Website',
        'post-deploy': 'npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --only production',
        env: { NODE_ENV: 'PRODUCTION' }
    },
    staging: {
        user: 'username',
        host: ['XXX.XXX.XX.XXX'],
        ref: 'origin/staging',
        repo: 'git@github.com:ghuser/Website.git',
        path: '/home/username/sites/WebsiteStaging',
        'post-deploy': 'npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --only staging',
        env: { NODE_ENV: 'STAGING' }
    }
}
};
```

When I deploy the application, I expect to see two processes - one called 'production' and one called 'staging'. These run code from the same repo, but from different branches.

I do see two processes, however, when I run `pm2 desc production` I can see that the script path is `/home/username/sites/WebsiteStaging/source/server.js`. This path should be `/home/username/sites/Website/source/server.js` as per the config file.

I've tried setting the script to `./server.js` and using the `cwd` parameter but the result has been the same.

The deploy commands I am using are `pm2 deploy production` and `pm2 deploy staging` and I have verified that both the `Website` and the `WebsiteStaging` folders are present on my server.

Is there something I'm missing here? Why would it be defaulting to the staging folder like this?

Comment: On the staging server when you do `pm2 desc staging` what do you get?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to delete the pm2 application and start it.

1. `pm2 delete production`
2. `pm2 start production`

When I ran `pm2 desc production`, I saw that the script path was incorrect, and nothing I did seemed to correct that path, short of the above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Seems it happend due to old `dump.pm2` that was not updated after changes to `ecosystem.config.js` were made.

Updating the startup script solved the issue

```
pm2 save
pm2 unstartup
pm2 startup
```